# Put php in js page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I would like to put a jQuery function which contain php in my main.js page. How can I do ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var r = parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>'); 
    var g = parseInt('<?php the_field('green'); ?>'); 
    var b = parseInt('<?php the_field('blue'); ?>');


    $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');

        var alpha = Math.min($(this).scrollTop() / 2000, 1);
        var r = Math.round((230-parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>')) * alpha + parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>')); 
        /* red : (fin - début + début) */
        var g = Math.round((230-parseInt('<?php the_field('green'); ?>')) * alpha + parseInt('<?php the_field('green'); ?>')); 
        /* red : (fin - début + début) */
        var b = Math.round((230-parseInt('<?php the_field('blue'); ?>')) * alpha + parseInt('<?php the_field('blue'); ?>')); 

   $(document).scroll(function() {
        /* red : (fin - début + début) */
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')');
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You can not put php on `core js file.(main.js)`.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You won't be able to execute the PHP code within your JavaScript because that's purely client side and can't execute on the server, but you can use AJAX or similar to call a PHP page and have the results returned.

Comment: The `<script>` element implies that this isn't actually a JavaScript file, but is an HTML file.  Regardless, you can put PHP code in anything that has a `.php` extension and/or is processed by the PHP engine server-side.  What have you tried and in what way is it not working?

Comment: @user3870112: If you want to clarify that question, do so on that question.  If there's information you'd like to add to this question, do so on this question.  Stack Overflow isn't a scavenger hunt.  As for this question, it's not really clear to me what the problem is here.  What does the code in the question become client-side?  In what way is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. PHP is processed in the backend by the PHP server, while JS is processed in the frontend by the browser (JS can be processed in the backend also with NodeJS, but that's a different topic)

Now, to accomplish what you are trying to do, create a `<script>` tag in your header **before** you load main.js, in which you add a global var that contains the colors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _COLORS_ = {
        r: parseInt('<?php the_field('red'); ?>'), 
        g: parseInt('<?php the_field('green'); ?>'),
        b: parseInt('<?php the_field('blue'); ?>')
  };
</script>
```

Then, in your main.js file, read from that variable: `_COLORS.r` or `_COLORS.g`, or `_COLORS.b`.